# Riak - Aggregration Group by Functions

Tags: mapreduce, riak

How do I perform aggregation group by like functions in RIAK?

Functions such as:

- Min
- Max
- Count
- Avg
- Stddev

In SQL this seems straight forward but I cannot find any examples in Riak online.

Answer (score 0):

Mapreduce - see the docs here - http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/mapreduce/